# A question related to Jordan's theorem on subgroups of $\mathrm{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups

$\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}$
$\newcommand{\mr}{\mathrm}$

For any positive integer $n$, let $f(n)$ be the minimal integer with the following
property:

> For any finite subgroup $G < \mr{GL}_n(\C)$ and positive integer $c$, if $G$ has a cyclic quotient of order at least $cf(n)$ then $G$ has a central cyclic subgroup of order at least $c$.

The fact that such an integer exists follows from Jordan's theorem, which says that there exists a function $J(n)$ with the property that any $G$ as above has an abelian normal subgroup $A$ with $[G:A] \leq J(n)$. One can then take $f(n)$ to be $J(n)^2$.

The optimal value of $J(n)$ is known, but it seems reasonable to expect that $f(n)$ is actually much smaller than $J(n)^2$ for large $n$. So the question is:

> Is there a (significantly) better upper bound for $f(n)$?

I would also be interested in lower bounds for $f(n)$. I think it's easy to see that it must be at least linear in $n$, but $J(n) = (n+1)!$ for large $n$ so there is a huge gap.

(I am mostly interested in the case where the representation of $G$ is irreducible, but this might not make much difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that if the given representation $G$ is primitive (that is, not only irreducible, but also not induced from any lower dimensional representation), then $f(n) = 6^{n-1}$ will do, by a theorem of Blichfeldt.

For if $A$ is any Abelian subgroup of $G$, then Blichfeldt's theorem tells us that $[A:A \cap Z(G)] \leq 6^{n-1}.$ In particular, if $A$ is cyclic and $|A| \geq c6^{n-1}$, then $G$ has a cyclic central subgroup of order at least $c$.

Then certainly if $G$ has a cyclic factor group of order $c6^{n-1}$, then $G$ contains an element of order at least $c6^{n-1},$ and Blichfeldt yields a cyclic central subgroup of order at least $c$.

I don't see how to adapt this to the imprimitive case at present.

Comment: Thank you. I did not know of Blichfeldt's theorem, what is a reference for it? I looked up some of his papers on linear groups but did not find the statement (and haven't yet been able to get hold of his book).

Comment: It may be easier to find a theorem of Frobenius ( whose proof is given in the book by Isaacs on Character theory), where the weaker bound with 12 in place of 6 is given. The theorem of Blichfeldt appears in the book "Group Representation Theory Part A" by L Dornhoff, for example. I give a "new" proof of the key prerequisite of Blichfeldt's result in my paper "On Linear Groups" , in Journal of Algebra, circa 1990.

Comment: Thanks for the references, I was able to borrow the book by Dornhoff. What I really want is a good bound for $f(n)$ as in the question, but with $\mathbb{C}$ replaced by a field of positive characteristic $p$. Using Collins's modular version of Jordan's theorem, one can get the same bound I gave (if $p$ is not too small). Is there a modular version of Blichfeldt's theorem which would imply the improved bound you gave in the modular setting (in the primitive case)?

Comment: Well, OK, people can only answer the question you ask. In the modular (irreducible) case,  I don't think there is an immediate analogue of Blichfeldt's result ( see below).  I was also worried about large cyclic p-factor groups, but they can't be greater than the next power of p which is at least n, so it might be possible to retrieve something. But if your characteristic p field is  large enough , you can get arbitrarily large Abelian subgroups of rank n which only meet the Fitting subgroup in scalar matrices ( eg in $GL(n,q)$  where $q = p^{r}$ and $r \to \infty$).

Comment: Thank you, I asked the question over $\mathbb{C}$ since if there was no good answer for in that case then there would be no hope in the modular setting.